# How I can load a R script into JRI and execute from Java?

Tags: java, r, command, jri

I'm using JRI to execute R from Java and I saw that JRI use the `eval()` method to execute the R commands. I have one R script for execution.

How I can load this script in JRI and execute it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can run an entire script with the R command `source()`

Comment: Is there a way to read the console output as it is running?